# My proof for symmetry group of the cube. Is it correct? Is anything unnecessary, can something be improved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G \leqslant S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$, and let $\phi: G \times X \rightarrow S_4$. Note that $X$ is the set of diagonals in $C$. Let $H \leqslant G$ be the group consisting of rotations, or direct isometries, on $X$. The elements of $H$ are:

- 6 quarter turns
- 3 half turns
- 8 rotations around diagonals
- 6 rotations around axes between opposite edges
- identity **1**

Thus $|H| = 24$. By considering $\phi: H \times X \rightarrow S_4$, it's clear that Ker$\{\phi\} = \{1\}$, which gives us that $H \cong S_4$, or $S_{d}(C) \cong S_4$. The central inversion of $C$, or the reflection through the centre of $C$ is the symmetry which leaves $C$ invariant, but changes its orientation. For instance, the diagonal $\{a,g\}$ would become $\{g,a\}$ by the central inversion. Denote this symmetry by $\rho$. Let $K = \{1,\rho\}$, and obviously $K \leqslant G$. Furthermore, since neither $1$ nor $\rho$ permutes the diagonals of $C$, we have $\sigma k \sigma^{-1} = k$ for all $\sigma \in G$ and $k \in K$, and thus $K \triangleleft G$. Now again, let $\phi: G \times X \rightarrow S_4$. Clearly Ker$\{\phi\} = K$, which gives us $G/K \cong$ Im$\{\phi\} = S_4$. Thus $|G| = |S_4||K| = 48$. We have $|H| = 24$, and since every coset of $H$ must have the same cardinality as $H$ and also since the cosets of $H$ partition $G$, it must be the case that $[G:H] = 2$ which gives $H \triangleleft G$.

Now, since every $\sigma \in H$ is a direct isometry, i.e. it preserves orientation, we have that $H \cap K = \{1\}$. Together with the fact that $H \triangleleft G$, $K \triangleleft G$ we have that $G$ is an internal direct product of $H,K$ and thus $G \cong H \times K = S_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Comment: I've been told that apparently I can't write the group of symmetries on the cube as a direct product of $S_4$ and $ \mathbb{Z}_2$ because the reflection doesn't commute with the rotations; what should it be instead? Every source cites it as the direct product but according to my lecturer this is incorrect.

Comment: @anonymousgoose That is true, but observe that the group I define as $K$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ does not contain any single reflections, rather it contains the product of reflections such that all diagonals chance direction. This element does commute with all reflections and rotations in $S_4$.

Comment: Hi Auclair - apologies for my previous comment - I realied my error after posting it - thank you for the clarification though :)

Comment: Hi. Don't apologize ;) Being mistaken and realising it is how we learn. Hope it helped, I know the construction is a bit awkward the first time you see it. Good luck in your future endeavours.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the help and understanding :)